# Does not display image in button

Tags: python, html, django

I'm just learning how to use Django and HTML, and I've run into a problem that my image is not displayed on the button, instead I get an icon with a leaf that has a hill and a cloud, I don't understand what the error is, and I will be grateful if someone that will help me fix it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button>
      <img src="images/i.jpg" alt="" style="position: relative; float: right; width: 320px; height: 320px">
  </button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You asked the exact same question 2 hours ago, there is no need to submit the same question again